# Round ribbon at the bottom right corner with icon and text in it

Tags: css, html

I am learning css and working on a project where I need to display a rounded ribbon at the bottom right corner of the web page along with icon and text in it. Below is the screenshot of the design that I am trying to achieve.[image].

So far I am able to display the ribbon but unable to keep the icon and text normal. Here is the link to Codepen: https://codepen.io/stephen0roper/pen/JeKdJV

CSS Code:

```
/* The ribbons */
.corner-ribbon{
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 50px;
  background: #e43;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: -30px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
  border-radius: 65px;
}

/* Custom styles */

.corner-ribbon.sticky{
  position: fixed;
}

.corner-ribbon.shadow{
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

/* Different positions */

.corner-ribbon.top-left{
  bottom: -50px;
  right: -100px;
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-315deg);
  background-color: red;
  width: 226px;
  height: 125px;
}


.corner-ribbon.red{background: #e43;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please look at this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aQmJjy?editors=1100

```css
/* The ribbons */

.corner-ribbon {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 50px;
  background: #e43;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: -30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
  border-radius: 65px;
}


/* Custom styles */

.corner-ribbon.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}

.corner-ribbon.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


/* Different positions */

.corner-ribbon.top-left {
  bottom: -50px;
  right: -100px;
  transform: rotate(-270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-315deg);
  background-color: red;
  width: 226px;
  height: 125px;
}

.corner-ribbon.red {
  background: #e43;
}

.rotate-text {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  item-align: center;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">
  <div class="rotate-text">
    <span>Some text</span>
    <i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is how I solved this puzzle:
1 remove the **line-height:100px;** in **.corner-ribbon** class

2 wrap the text and icon into a div and add a class"stop-rotate", and just**need to rotate it back 45deg**:

```
   .stop-rotate{
  display:inline;
  padding-top:30px;
  float:left;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  text-align:center;
}
```

[image: 2]

3 edit the html tags, and change the icon to **fa-2x**

```
    <div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">
  <div class="stop-rotate">Some text
  <i class="fas fa-camera fa-2x" style="display:block"></i>   
  </div>
</div>
```

I have saved the Pen(for those who may need: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OaRpOd ),you may still see the result and may need to edit the size a little bit.
[image]
Hope this helps.:)